# create dictionary from two lists

Tags: python, list, tuples

I'm new to this and I'm having some issues finishing up a part of my homework. basically I have 2 lists:

```
names = ["Jerry", "Fernando", "Radu", "Juan", "Brie", "Dani", "Fallon", "Nina", "Max", "Mike", "Johnny", "Saul", "Simon", "Billy"]
ages = [27, 27, 23, 27, 27, 23, 33, 32, 25, 32, 26, 26, 29, 24]
```

What I'm trying to achieve is a dictionary that looks like that:

```
{'Jerry': {'age': 27},
 'Fernando': {'age': 27},
 # ...
 'Billy': {'age': 24},
}
```

I used tuples to display it like this `[('Jerry', 27), ('Fernando', 27), ..., ('Billy', 24)]` but I can't figure out how to display it in a dictionary with each key, value on a new line.

Answer (score 4):

Use a dictionary comprehension:

```
{name: {'age': age} for name, age in zip(names, ages)}
```

Demo:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> names = ["Jerry", "Fernando", "Radu", "Juan", "Brie", "Dani", "Fallon", "Nina", "Max", "Mike", "Johnny", "Saul", "Simon", "Billy"]
>>> ages = [27, 27, 23, 27, 27, 23, 33, 32, 25, 32, 26, 26, 29, 24]
>>> {name: {'age': age} for name, age in zip(names, ages)}
{'Mike': {'age': 32}, 'Simon': {'age': 29}, 'Johnny': {'age': 26}, 'Max': {'age': 25}, 'Juan': {'age': 27}, 'Jerry': {'age': 27}, 'Fernando': {'age': 27}, 'Nina': {'age': 32}, 'Billy': {'age': 24}, 'Radu': {'age': 23}, 'Dani': {'age': 23}, 'Fallon': {'age': 33}, 'Brie': {'age': 27}, 'Saul': {'age': 26}}
>>> pprint(_)
{'Billy': {'age': 24},
 'Brie': {'age': 27},
 'Dani': {'age': 23},
 'Fallon': {'age': 33},
 'Fernando': {'age': 27},
 'Jerry': {'age': 27},
 'Johnny': {'age': 26},
 'Juan': {'age': 27},
 'Max': {'age': 25},
 'Mike': {'age': 32},
 'Nina': {'age': 32},
 'Radu': {'age': 23},
 'Saul': {'age': 26},
 'Simon': {'age': 29}}
```

Comment: derp.  yours is better :-)

Comment: @mgilson: I think it's useful to see both here. I'd probably write it Martijn's way in this case, but in a larger case, where there were multiple steps along the way to transform, you're often going to end up zipping the keys and values and calling `dict` in the end.

Comment: @mgilson: I am surprised how often people forget about dictionary comprehensions. Then again, I often forget about feeding key-value tuples to `dict()`!

Comment: how about if I want to add a new key (max_number_of_drinks) to each user where the value is the integer part of the operation age/4 i.e: "jerry":{"age":27, "max_number_of_drinks":6}

Comment: @RaduAndrei: just add that to the value expression: `{'age': age, 'max_number_of_drings': age // 4}`.

Answer (score 1):

You could zip it:

```
dict(zip(names, ({'age': a} for a in ages)))
```

Comment: *Note, this would be deleted except @abarnert thought it was useful to see it this way as well.  If I was OP, I'd take Martijn's answer :-)